# Double Squares: counting numbers which are sums of two perfect squares

Tags: algorithm, math

Source: [Facebook Hacker Cup](http://www.facebook.com/hackercup) [Qualification Round 2011](http://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?round=4)

A double-square number is an integer X which can be expressed as the sum of two perfect squares. For example, 10 is a double-square because 10 = 3<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup>. Given X, how can we determine the number of ways in which it can be written as the sum of two squares? For example, 10 can only be written as 3<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup> (we don't count 1<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> as being different). On the other hand, 25 can be written as 5<sup>2</sup> + 0<sup>2</sup> or as 4<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup>.

You need to solve this problem for 0 ≤ X ≤ 2,147,483,647.

Examples:

- 10 => 1
- 25 => 2
- 3 => 0
- 0 => 1
- 1 => 1

Comment: Just noting, this round has now ended.

Comment: wasn't popularized as much as codejam. Just came to know about it.

Comment: @Senthil Probably a good thing as the platform experienced a number of problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Factor the number n, and check if it has a prime factor p with odd valuation, such that p = 3 (mod 4). It does if and only if n is not a sum of two squares.

The number of solutions has a closed form expression involving the number of divisors of n. See [this, Theorem 3](http://www2-fs.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/~borchert/ArithmeticalCircuits/Grosswald.pdf) for a precise statement.

Comment: IIRC, this is the best solution. (The same problem was on SPOJ or somewhere.) For the factoring, it also helps to precompute a list of primes upto √MAX using a sieve.)

Comment: This algorithm is not fast as simple brute force one, because brute force algorithm is O(√n), but finding primes lower than `√n` with sieve is O(√n log log (n)), and if we assume log log n for this case is small, still it's O(√n) and also number of single operations on this is bigger than simple ones.

Comment: @Saeed: you compute the primes once only. Then it is factoring (which is indeed O(sqrt(n)) worst case, but much better on average). One way or the other, you need to brute force.

Comment: Ok, so you saying finding primes lower than 2,147,483,647 and save it in array, there are around 99940774 primes lower than int limit (n/ln(n)), it will takes huge amount of memory, also still the number of primes lower than √n is √n/ln(√n) which is around √n, so if your basic computations are bigger than simple brute force algorithm basic computations ( ln(n) times), your running time is still slower than simple one. and if you wanna compare it simply, write your code, compare with i.e marcog simple algorithm.

Comment: @Saeed: you have to compute primes up to 46340. You could do it by hand if you wanted.

Comment: @Alexandre C, this is still O(√n loglogn) for initialization, and if you think it's faster (after init) to compute it by hand, do it, also if is not faster (by hand) still you can compare your solution with normal way, the order is not very difference in your case and may be is not good, if the number of computation in `Theorm 3` is bigger than ln(n) (with given bound) your algorithm is slow, in all if you provide some code to show how you wanna compute it, is good. (not how to precompute primes, I mean your base algorithm).

Answer (score 6):

Here is my simple answer in `O(sqrt(n))` complexity

```
x^2 + y^2 = n
x^2 = n-y^2 
x = sqrt(n - y^2)
```

x should be integer so `(n-y^2)` should be perfect square. Loop to `y=[0, sqrt(n)]` and check whether `(n-y^2)` is perfect square or not

**Pseudocode** :

```
count = 0;
for y in range(0, sqrt(n))
    if( isPerfectSquare(n - y^2))
         count++
return count/2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a much simpler solution:

```
create list of squares in the given range (that's 46340 values for the example given)

for each square value x
  if list contains a value y such that x + y = target value (i.e. does [target - x] exist in list)
    output √x, √y as solution (roots can be stored in a std::map lookup created in the first step)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping through all pairs (a, b) is infeasible given the constrains on X. There is a faster way though!

For fixed a, we can work out b: b = √(X - a<sup>2</sup>). b won't always be an integer though, so we have to check this. Due to precision issues, perform the check with a small tolerance: if b is x.99999, we can be fairly certain it's an integer. So we loop through all possible values of a and count all cases where b is an integer. We need to be careful not to double-count, so we place the constraint that a <= b. For X = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>, a will be at most √(X/2) with this constraint.

Here is an implementation of this algorithm in C++:

```
int count = 0;
// add EPS to avoid flooring x.99999 to x
for (int a = 0; a <= sqrt(X/2) + EPS; a++) {
    int b2 = X - a*a; // b^2
    int b = (int) (sqrt(b2) + EPS);
    if (abs(b - sqrt(b2)) < EPS) // check b is an integer
        count++;
}
cout << count << endl;
```

[See it on ideone with sample input](http://ideone.com/dCgnn)

Comment: `For X = a2 + b2, a and b will each be at most √(X/2)` errr... what? Doesn't this directly contradict the example you gave yourself in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version which is trivially O(sqrt(N)) and avoids all loop-internal branches.

Start by generating all squares up to the limit, easily done without any multiplications, then initialize a l and r index.

In each iteration you calculate the sum, then update the two indices and the count based on a comparison with the target value. This is sqrt(N) iterations to generate the table and maximum sqrt(N) iterations of the search loop. Estimated running time with a reasonable compiler is max 10 clock cycles per sqrt(N), so for a maximum input value if 2^31 (sqrt(N) ~= 46341) this should correspond to less than 500K clock cycles or a few tenths of a second:

```
unsigned countPairs(unsigned n)
{
    unsigned sq = 0, i;
    unsigned square[65536];

    for (i = 0; sq <= n; i++) {
        square[i] = sq;
        sq += i+i+1;
    }

    unsigned l = 0, r = i-1, count = 0;

    do {
        unsigned sum = square[l] + square[r];
        l += sum <= n;       // Increment l if the sum is <= N
        count += sum == n;   // Increment the count if a match
        r -= sum >= n;       // Decrement r if the sum is >= N
    } while (l <= r);
    return count;
}
```

A good compiler can note that the three compares at the end are all using the same operands so it only needs a single CMP opcode followed by three different conditional move operations (CMOVcc).

Answer (score 0):

I was in a hurry, so solved it using a rather brute-force approach (very similar to marcog's) using Python 2.6.

```
def is_perfect_square(x):
    rt = int(math.sqrt(x))
    return rt*rt == x

def double_sqaures(n):
    rng = int(math.sqrt(n))
    ways = 0
    for i in xrange(rng+1):
        if is_perfect_square(n - i*i):
            ways +=1
    if ways % 2 == 0:
        ways = ways // 2
    else:
        ways = ways // 2 + 1
    return ways
```

Note: `ways` will be odd when the number is a perfect sqaure.

Answer (score -1):

The number of solutions (x,y) of

x^2+y^2=n

over the integers is exactly 4 times the number of divisors of n congruent to 1 mod 4.
Similar identities exist also for the problems

x^2 + 2y^2 = n

and

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = n.

Comment: -1 for not caring to do proper research.  There is such a simple formula, but it is different from what you describe. For more information, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html

Comment: According to your statement, n=9 would have 8 solutions, because it has two divisors d with d mod 4 = 1 (namely, d=1 and d=9). However, n=9 has no solutions at all!

Comment: @vog `9 = 3^2 + 0^2` in the same way `25 = 5^2 + 0^2` in the problem statement. Not defending the answer, just nitpicking.